# How do we version a new endpoint being added to an existing API

Tags: api, rest, asp.net-web-api, aws-api-gateway, api-versioning

We have our API versioning strategy based on URL.
I have couple of scenarios to add new enpoints , where I could not find any strategical reference for this.

**Scenario 1:**
An existing API having endpoints varyingly ranging from  versions v1 to v4. Few endpoints are upto V2,  few are upto V3, and few at v4.
In this situation If I have to add a new endpoint, Should I begin the version for the new endpoint at V4?  Is there any standards for it.

**Scenario 2**
This is the different scenario. one of the API GW spanned across multiple microservices, and the micro services are grouped by resources within the gateway. so a resource have a one on one mapping against a service.
Similarly different API versioning exists btw resources here. Few resources were upto V3 and few are up to v5. if a new endpoint is required to be added to a resource which is already upto v3, should we add a new endpoint in v3 or should we create a v5 version of resource to add that specific endpoint?

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You're unlikely find a *standard* way of doing things. The closest thing to a standard is what Fielding and the HTTP specifications say themselves. You should expect these questions to enlist many subjective opinions. Here's my bias opinion based on experience and a deep understanding of the specifications...

Conceptually, there's no real problem with adding new endpoints to an existing API. Where this might be problematic is if your API is public and with public documentation. Once an API version is released, it should be immutable so that clients can rely on it. If you're adding surface area to your API, then I would recommend you create a new version. If you're unsure what that version will shape up to be in totality, you can always start with a pre-release version; for example, `4.0-preview.1`.

Your second question seems to ask whether you should have *symmetrical* versions. You *can*, but it's solely at your discretion. You indicated that you have microservices, so unless you are building out an API for an entire product or suite, it is more flexible to allow an API to evolve independently. This will organically result in heterogenous API versions over time. That shouldn't be a problem IMHO. The key to making that manageable is to define a sound versioning policy, such as `N-2` supported versions.

You've already elected to version by URL segment, so there's no going back. Versioning this way leads to a spider web of different URLs when the versions are not symmetrical. This is just one of the many problems you may encounter. Hypermedia is almost all but impossible to achieve when versioning by URL unless the versions are symmetrical. Ultimately, versioning by URL segment is **not** RESTful, despite being popular, because it violates the *Uniform Interface* constraint. The URL path *is* the resource identifier. `v3/order/42` and `v4/order/42` are not different resources, they are different *representations*. In the same way, I can ask for `order/42` as `application/json` or `application/xml`, but they are not different API versions, even though they look completely different over the wire.

As an example, if you retrieve `v2/order/42` and it has a link to `customer/42`, but the *Customer* API supports `2.0` and `3.0`, how do you know which link to provide? If the client only knows how to talk `v3/customer/42` and you give them `v2/customer/42`, it might break them. Furthermore, what happens if the *Customer* API doesn't support `2.0` at all? The *Order* API has to incorrectly assume `v2` is a valid or it has to be coupled into knowing which versions are supported; both of which are not good. In all cases, the server still doesn't know what the client really wants. It is the client's responsibility to tell the server what it wants. Every other method of versioning does not have this problem as the URLs are always consistent. Let's say you version by query string with `api-version`, another popular choice. If you provide a link to `customer/42`, the link is valid regardless of API version. It's the client's job to know and append `?api-version=<value>` to indicate to the server how they want to *query* the resource. This is why Fielding says that media type negotiation is the *only* way to version an API. It's hard to argue with the G.O.A.T., but using the query string or another header doesn't explicitly violate any constraints, even if media type negotiation would be better.